# set column width when exporting to pdf when using datatables.net

Tags: pdf, datatables

hi i have this table that i wanted to export but the width of one column is so long when the content is only short and it makes the layout not looking good when it is exported to pdf im using the codes from datatables.net when exporting and here is my code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var day = currentDate.getDate()
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()

    var d = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
    $('#detailTable').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [{
            extend: 'excelHtml5',
            title: d + ' Purchase Orders'
        }, {
            extend: 'csvHtml5',
            title: d + ' Purchase Orders'
        }, {
            extend: 'pdfHtml5',
            title: d + ' Purchase Orders',
            orientation: 'landscape',
            pageSize: 'LEGAL',
            exportOptions: {
                columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

is there a way where i can set the width of a specific column? thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `customize` callback to alter PDFmakes' "style dictionary". If you want to force the #2 column to be `100px` or max `100px` in width, do this :

```js
{
  extend: 'pdfHtml5',
  title: d + ' Purchase Orders',
  orientation: 'landscape',
  pageSize: 'LEGAL',
  exportOptions: {
     columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
  },
  //-------------------------- 
  customize : function(doc) {
     doc.styles['td:nth-child(2)'] = { 
       width: '100px',
       'max-width': '100px'
     }
  }
}
```

This will pass the CSS style rule

```css
td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

to PDFmake. See the documentation -> http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted go for section "Style dictionaries"

Comment: hi i downloaded the pdfmake.min.js and the vfs_fonts.js then here is my current code `{
       extend: 'pdfHtml5',
       title: d + ' Purchase Orders',
       orientation: 'landscape',
       pageSize: 'LEGAL',
       exportOptions: {
          columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
       },
       
       customize : function(doc) 
       {
          doc.defaultStyle ['td:nth-child(6)'] = { 
            width: '500px',
            'max-width': '500px'
          }
       }
     }` im not able to adjust the output tho

Comment: @BourneShady - `td:nth-child(i)` is not zero based, it starts from 1.  Perhaps you have more luck with `td:nth-child(7)`  ...?

Answer (score 0):

I could not make the "td:nth-child" solution work, but this worked well for me:

```
customize : function(doc) {
   doc.content[1].table.widths = [40,120,'*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*','*'];
}
```

You must have as many elements in the "widths" array as there are columns in the table.  "*" means equally-spaced columns (see [pdfmake documentation](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/tables/))

You can also set the alignment of columns as follows (my example using jQuery but easily adapted):

```
customize : function(doc) {
  $.each(doc.content[1].table.body, function (r, row) {
     $.each(row, function (c, column) {
        // set the alignment of every column except the first 2
        if (c > 1) column.alignment = "right";     
     });
  });
```