# Styling only specific columns of a datatable table in pdfHtml5 using pdfmake

Tags: javascript, datatables, pdfmake

Styling only specific columns of a datatable table in pdfHtml5 using pdfmake. I want to export a datatable table in pdf and style only a specific column or exclude specific column with nowrap.

With doc.defaultStyle.noWrap = true; I can noWrap the whole table when exporting to pdf. But how can I apply noWrap only to a certain column? So e.g. only to column 5 and 7 ?

```
{
extend:    'pdfHtml5',
text:      'PDF',
exportOptions: {
    columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
},
customize: function(doc) {
    doc.defaultStyle.noWrap = true;
}
}
```

And alternative nowrap all columns except for column 0 and 1 ??? There is a example with width [set column width when exporting to pdf when using datatables.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34061801/set-column-width-when-exporting-to-pdf-when-using-datatables-net). I already tried this but it's not working

```
doc.styles['td:nth-child(5)'] = { 
        noWrap: true
}

//doc.content.table.noWrap = true;
//doc.content.style.noWrap = true;
```